# Strings containing tags are not rendered properly inside <td>

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to show how `**hello**` will be converted to `<b>hello</b>` and rendered as **hello**. I made a table for this and you can check it here in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLod3fgc/7/)

#### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Output</th>
      <th>View</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="example in examples" v-bind:key="example">
      <td>{{example.input}}</td>
      <td><pre>{{example.output}}</pre></td>
      <td>{{example.output}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### JS

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    examples: [{input:"**a**", output:"<b>a</b>"}]
  }
})
```

Everything works fine except for the third column, which is `<td>{{example.output}}</td>`. I checked that the column was replaced to `<td><b>a</b></td>` from the inspector, but the bold style isn't applied. Does it have to do with Vue? When I type the value `<b>a</b>` instead of passing the data through vue, I can see the string bolded. How can I make it styled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean something like this `v-html`?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!',
    examples: [{input:"**a**", output:"<b>a</b>"}, {input:"*a*", output:"<i>a</i>"}]
  },
  methods: {
   toggle: function(todo){
     todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Output</th>
      <th>View</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(example, index) in examples" v-bind:key="index">
      <td>{{example.input}}</td>
      <td ><pre v-html="example.output"></pre></td>
      <td v-html="example.output"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `v-html` directive to render string as html. Changing `<td>{{example.output}}</td>` of the third `td` to `<td v-html="example.output"></td>` should work